# Xcode "po/print" of uint32_t variable prints out a 64-bit value

Tags: xcode, lldb

given the following:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef uint32_t UIAccessibilityNotifications;
UIKIT_EXTERN UIAccessibilityNotifications UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification;
```

in the xcode lldb,

```
(lldb) print UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification
(void *) $7 = 0x00000409000003f1
```

which is a 64-bit value ?! its type is given as a pointer, so i guess they assigned a pointer as a value to a 32-bit typed variable... but how is it preserved after assignment?

for example, if i now do,

```
UIAccessibilityNotifications temp = UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification;
```

then,

```
(lldb) print temp
(UIAccessibilityNotifications) $8 = 1009
```

which is == 0x3f1, as expected; so i only keep 32-bit portion of the 64-bit value after assignment. both temp and UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification have same type declarations.

so how come im getting 64-bit value when printing out a 32-bit variable?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Xcode 7.3, using a trivial program (no changes to an iPhone single-view template; just put a breakpoint at the end of `didFinishLauchingWithOptions:` and checked the debugger). How exactly are you generating it?

Comment: hmm; i was debugging this on a device which is arm64.. i'm also on xcode 7.3